# Attaching an end-effector .stl or .xaml file with a .xacro Industrial Robot and loading on Gazebo via ROS

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I have build an end effector with the use of the Rhino, where the file can be saved as an .stl or as an .xaml. I would now like to attach the end effector to an Industrial Robot, particularly the ABB IRB-120 Robot, and load it onto Gazebo. I have also managed to install the robot itself via ROS and the arm_controllers file.

The next step would to load the robot with the end effector, where I am referencing to the following tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages
However, I noticed that the end effector in this case is a .xacro file. Is it possible to load a .xacro robot and attach an end effector made using a .stl file or a .xaml file?
Thanks in advance,
Jacob

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/398367/attaching-an-end-effector-.stl-or-.xaml-file-with-a-.xacro-industrial-robot-and-loading-on-gazebo-via-ros./) by [JCatania](https://answers.ros.org/users/100140/jcatania/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2022-04-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to load a .xacro robot and attach an end effector made using a .stl file or a .xaml file?

no, not directly. And `.xaml` files cannot be used at all I believe.

In a URDF (which a `.xacro` file in the end is turned in to), you define the kinematic structure of your robot + attach meshes to the `link` elements which are part of that structure. Those meshes can be `.stl`s (or `.dae`, or anything supported by Assimp), but they can only be attached *to* `link` elements. You cannot just have a `mesh` element and attach it to the kinematic structure. That's not how URDF works (or: was designed to be used).

So in your case, where you have a `.stl`, you'd have to create a minimal `.xacro` which probably defines only a single `link`, the `base_link` (this name is arbitrary, you can use whatever you want, but `base_link` is a good ROS convention to follow). That `base_link` can then be used to attach your `.stl` to.

As an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://wiki.ros.org/xacro">
  <xacro:macro name="my_eef" params="prefix">

    <!-- this EEF model has only a single link: base_link, which is used
         to 'attach' the STL mesh to which fully represents the geometry
         of the real EEF.

         Note the use of both a visual (ie: detailed) quality mesh and
         a collision (ie: coarse) mesh. This is to facilitate tools like
         motion planners, which often use coarse models to speed up mesh
         to mesh collision checking.
    -->
    <link name="${prefix}base_link">
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://my_eef_pkg/meshes/visual/base_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="grey">
          <color rgba="0.2 0.2 0.2 1.0"/>
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://my_eef_pkg/meshes/collision/base_link.stl"/>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>

    <!-- a default tool frame (might be better to broadcast a static TF frame
         for this instead, but this is just an example).

         Note: this follows conventions of industrial robotics, and rotates the
         frame such that Z+ points forward, X+ points up.
    -->
    <link name="${prefix}tool_frame" />
    <joint name="${prefix}base_link-tool_frame" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${pi} ${-pi/2.0} 0" />
      <parent link="${prefix}base_link" />
      <child link="${prefix}tool_frame" />
    </joint>
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

Put your EEF `.xacro` in its own package, and now you can follow the tutorial(s) you already linked/found.

Note that this defines a `xacro:macro`. So you'd have to instantiate it. You cannot use it directly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JCatania](https://answers.ros.org/users/100140/jcatania/) on 2022-04-02**:
Yes. it worked well. Thanks!

However, what I did is that I used the same .stl file instead of two separate files. Note that I created the file via Rhino.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-03**:\

> However, what I did is that I used the same .stl file instead of two separate files.

that will prevent consumers of your `.xacro` from optimising their algorithms when working with mesh data. MoveIt for instance will have to collision check with the fully detailed mesh, instead of with a coarser approximation.

Using a suitably downsampled version of your `.stl` could have a significant positive effect on performance.

> Note that I created the file via Rhino.

I'm not sure I understand what this implies.

Meshes generated by modelling tools tend to be overly detailed.

How big is the `.stl` (as in: in bytes)?

**Comment by [JCatania](https://answers.ros.org/users/100140/jcatania/) on 2022-04-03**:
The file is 2.9 kB. It must have both visual and collision meshes, as when I loaded the end effector on Gazebo, it loaded correctly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-04-03**:\

> It must have both visual and collision meshes, as when I loaded the end effector on Gazebo, it loaded correctly.

No, that's not how it works.

Your `.stl` file contains a single shape. If you don't specify a different file, your "high quality" model will just be used for both purposes.

> The file is 2.9 kB.

Then it's likely OK to reuse the same file for both purposes.